# Radio Button Reset

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using this package [Radio Button](https://www.npmjs.com/package/radio-buttons-react-native). It's working fine but I need to reset the selected value, for that I can not find any solution there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change state to render new radio button - https://snack.expo.dev/iiHkFYpLV

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from "react-native";
import RadioButtonRN from 'radio-buttons-react-native';

const App = () => {

  const [show,setShow] = React.useState(true);
  const data = [
  {
    label: 'data 1'
  },
  {
    label: 'data 2'
  }
  ];

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    if(!show) setShow(true)
  },[show])

  const resetHandler = () =>{
    setShow(false)
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    {show && 
            <RadioButtonRN
          data={data}
          selectedBtn={(e) => console.log(e)}
        />
    }

        <Button title='reset' onPress={resetHandler}  />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
paddingTop:100,
  }
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

the package does not have the reset functionality but there is a PR pending for the same feature. Whole package is in a single file only, so what you can do is copy package file to your code and add the feature related code from the PR.

or you can use another package ;)

Comment: you can update update package file component like this to add reset feature
https://snack.expo.dev/O0S7Of83f

Comment: It's showing error  undefined is not a function in this line ..... ref.current.resetRadio();

Comment: have you added resetRadio() function in RadioButtonRN.js file?